# Why does mongo's rs.status() show secondary as healthy when its offline

Tags: mongodb, replica-set

I logged into a secondary & did use admin; db.shutdownServer(), then I powered off the whole server with "sudo shutdown". On the primary server I am running rs.status().

For the secondary that is offline, I see:

    `"health" : 1,
    "state" : 2,
    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",`

I also see that `lastHeartbeat` updates, but `lastHeartbeatRecv` does not update. I expect the health/state fields to change if the member is offline, but it does not. How can I monitor my replica set members to see if they are offline?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB are you running? Can you include the full `rs.status()` output? If a secondary is shut down as described, the expected [replica set member state](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-states/) would be "DOWN" and the values you've quoted from  `rs.status()` should be: `"health": 0, "state": 8, "stateStr": "(not reachable/healthy)"`.

Comment: Also, approximately how long did you wait after shutting down the secondary and checking `rs.status()` on the primary? Did you continue re-checking to see if the state of the down secondary changed after more elapsed time?

Comment: Yep I checked for 5+ minutes, the `lastHeartbeat` kept updating, but `lastHeartbeatRect` never changed, each time I checked. What is the timeout before the `health` field should changed, maybe I did not wait long enough?

Comment: You need to provide more information on your environment -- something is amiss if you are waiting minutes and the secondary state isn't changing in `rs.status()`. What specific version of MongoDB are you running (as reported by `db.version()` in the `mongo` shell) and what is your O/S version? Can you include the full `rs.status()` output? Can you also include some details on the network topology (are all nodes on the same network, is that local hosting or a cloud provider, .. )?